# Error Installing APKs

Tags: android, android-studio, android-install-apk

17:03   Failed to finalize session: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Split lib_slice_9_apk was defined multiple times

17:03   Session 'app': Error Installing APKs

What should I do?

**logcat -**

```
05-27 13:56:05.979 1302-1302/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-as.hyb
                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-as.hyb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
                                              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:187)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:441)
                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can sometimes by caused by issues in your ports. You need to follow these steps to fix this.

1. Go to task manager and kill the service named "adb.exe".
2. If you are using a personal computer , then try switching between your front and back ports.
3. If you are using a laptop, then try switching between your available ports.